# Why my multi dimensional array's property isn't getting updated

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
var isEmpty = true;
for(let i = 0; i< members.length; i++)
{   
    var member = members[i];
    if(member && member[3]){
        isEmpty = false;
        break;
    }   
}

if(isEmpty) {
    var somePrefix = "123 -"
    for(let i = 0; i< members.length; i++)
    {   
        var member = members[i];
        if(member && member[2]){
            member[3] = somePrefix + i;
        }   
    }
}

console.log(member[1][3])  // just testing
```

Output :

> undefined

Here is what's happening,

1. Checking X property is empty for all members
2. If it is then, auto populate it, if any of the property is filled in then leave it as it is

Comment: First you have `member && member[3]` and in the second loop `member && member[2]`. Is it by design? There might be an item where both `[3]` and `[2]` are empty and then you won't ever write anything. Also you're looping with `i <= members.length` which is definitely wrong (`<`, index is 0 based) if `members` is a normal plain array.

Comment: Can you show us `members` please?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes, it is by design unfortunately..., for second amended yet oyt is same

Comment: Does going through it in debug, step by step, highlights anything weird (=it executes all the things you think it should)?

Comment: Thank you guys for your time, it happened to be a typing mistake while testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a typo, I was using member instead of members while testing it...

Changed,

```
console.log(member[1][3])
```

into,

```
console.log(members[1][3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done a mistake in the first `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= members.length; i++) {
  var member = members[i];
  if (member && member[3]) {
    isEmpty = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

This will not check that `X` property is empty for all members. As soon as it finds a member that `exists` and `has value X`, the `loop` will break and rest of the code will not do anything as `isEmpty` is `false`.

The code should be written like this:-

```js
const members = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]];

let isEmpty = true;

for(let i =0; i<members.length; i++) {
    let member = members[i]
    if (member && member[3]) {
        isEmpty = false
    }
}
if(!isEmpty) {
    let someprefix = "123 - "
    for(let i =0; i<members.length; i++){
        var member = members[i]
        if (member && member[2]) {
            member[3] = someprefix + i;
        }
    }
}
console.log(members[0][3])
```

Comment: That seems to be by design: _"...if any of the property is filled in then leave it as it is."_ and _"...property is empty for **all** members."_. Also note that exiting the loop with `break` or keeping looping like in your example have exactly the same effect.